# Best practice to check a JSP conditional with multiple options

Tags: java, jsp

I need to check in a JSP if a string is equal to a list of possibilities. The solution should be applied to the JSP (not access to the Java code) and I'm avoiding to use scriptlets, but to be honest right now I'm tempted to use it. Currently the code looks like this:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${name eq 'Edgar' or
        name eq 'Mike' or
        name eq 'Tijuana' or
        name eq 'Mozell' or
        name eq 'Dominga' or
        name eq 'Genie' or
        name eq 'Lacey' or
        name eq 'Eliza' or
        name eq 'Dona' or
        name eq 'Leigh' or
        name eq 'Manda' or
        name eq 'Amelia' or
        name eq 'Bob'}">
            <%-- Stuff --%>
    </c:when> 
    <c:otherwise> 
        <%-- other stuff --%>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

This solution works but is ugly enough to come here and ask for your opinion. How would you improve it?

Thanks!

Comment: What if you put the names in a `set` and check if `name` is in the `set`?

Comment: This doesn't seem to make sense. Why would you hardcode names in a JSP file? Fetch them from a database or something similar.

Comment: I agree with xehpuk, you are dealing with business logic in JSP, don't do that..it's really bad.

Comment: I agree too, I wish that I could use a database or even the Java code but all that I can use to fix it is the JSP. I'm trying to make it less ugly but for sure I won't feel proud of this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefere use something like this:

```
<% if (PredefinedNameSet.contains(name)) { %> 
    jsp-stuff 
<% } else { %> 
    other jsp-stuff 
<% } %>
```

Comment: Please don't do that.

Comment: @xehpuk it's not *best practice*, but solves OP's problem. In real applications those names should be contained in database or external resource.

Comment: Your snippet misses the initialization of `PredefinedNameSet`. I think OP's solution is "cleaner".